# React Native, Nested Scroll Views, Cross Directional Scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, react-native, scrollview

I am trying to set up a ListView-esque list and have each list item be horizontally scrollable within the vertically scrollable ListView. I figured out that the ListView will never work in this use case so I am now using nested ScrollViews which have more control. The parent ScrollView has no props or settings beside some styles and each list item has a large amount of constraints.

I am using this as my List Item code:

```
<View style={styles.row}>
    <AnimatedScrollView 
      ref={'animatedSwiperRow'}
      horizontal={true}
      automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
      showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      keyboardDismissMode={'on-drag'}
      scrollEnabled={this.state.scrollEnabled}
      directionalLockEnabled={true}
      style={[{flex: 1, height: 85}, {backgroundColor: bgColor}]}
      onScroll={this._animateScroll.bind(this)}
      scrollEventThrottle={15}
      onMomentumScrollBegin={this.takeAction.bind(this)}>

      <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleViewListItem.bind(this)}>

        <View style={styles.contentRow}>
          <Image
            style={styles.traitIcon}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
            source={{uri: this.props.logo_url}} />

          <View style={styles.contentColumn}>
            <Text style={styles.trait}>
              {this.props.effect}
            </Text>

            <Text style={styles.short_summary}>{this.props.short_summary}</Text>
          </View>

          <Image
            style={styles.profileTypeIcon}
            resizeMode={'contain'}
            source={{uri: this.props.logo_url}} />
        </View>

      </TouchableOpacity>

    </AnimatedScrollView>
  </View>
```

My ListView-esque ScrollView is this:

```
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <ScrollView style={styles.outerScroll}>
      {this.state.dataSource.map(this.renderListItem, this)}
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

`this.renderListItem` is a function that simply builds the ListItem obj. So each of these code blocks are in separated render functions.

What I am trying to accomplish is this tutorial [here](http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-animated-listview-row-swipe/) and it is giving me troubles. I have a decent model to play with as of now but there are so many gross bugs. The first bug I am trying to get rid of is that each list item's ScrollView has the ability to scroll vertically and thats a problem because I want all vertical scrolls sent to the parent ScrollView which is acting as my ListView for now. All horizontal scrolls I need to swipe the row only horizontally. Obviously this isn't the case right now, since most vertical scrolls scroll only the single list item instead of the entire list like I want.